# What to do if "webpage is missing meta language information"?

Tags: html, google-search-console

A webmaster-tools utility complains that my page is **missing meta language information**.

What should I do if my page contains mixture of text in multiple languages (all Western European languages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most “webmaster-tools” complaints are best ignored (or not read at all). To get help with specific messages, please identify the tool, the message, and your URL.

A mixture of languages is a problem in itself, and best avoided by putting different language versions into different pages. If you need a mix of languages, use the `lang` attribute to specify the language of each part.

There is very little useful that you can do with `meta` tags, regarding a mixture of languages.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Multi-regional and multilingual sites](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192) article? It provides some good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the URL: https://example.com/en/page-a/

The Hint would trigger for this URL if it does not specify HTML language, using any of the methods below;

The "content-language" meta tag in the :

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us">
```

The  element in the :

```
<html lang="en-us">
```

The  element in the :

```
<title lang="en-us">
```